# Problema ao ler arquivo csv que possui virgula e ponto e virgula

Tags: csv, golang

O código lê o arquivo com sucesso até travar na linha 6, que tem uma vírgula no meio, tirei a vírgula da linha 6, e o err foi para a linha 8 e assim em diante. Como leio o arquivo? ignorando as virgulas, primeira vez mexendo com arquivo csv.

Exemplo csv:

```
Produtos;preco;data
...
camiseta,outros;60;20/10/20019  (a vírgula separando)

O erro:
2019/10/22 20:19:49 record on line 6: wrong number of fields
exit status 1
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    csvfile, ferr := os.Open("teste/ncm.csv")
    if ferr != nil {
        log.Fatal(ferr)
    }
    r := csv.NewReader(csvfile)

    for {
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(record)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que no `CSV`, a virgula (`,`) é o delimitador para cada informação. No seu código aparentemente você está utilizando o ponto e virgula (`;`) como delimitador, mas o encoder não sabe disso.

Como a primeira linha não possui nenhuma vírgula, o encoder supõe que cada linha terá apenas uma informação, mas ao encontrar uma linha como uma vírgula ele lança um erro, pois a linha teria duas informações, e portanto seu CSV estaria inconsistente.

O que você precisa fazer é definir o ponto e vírgula como seu delimitador, faça isso da seguinte maneira:

```
r := csv.NewReader(csvfile)
r.Comma = ';'
```

Se todas as linhas do seu arquivo possuir o mesmo número de ponto e virgulas, você conseguirá ler o arquivo sem erros.

Comment: Value! Agora ele leu o arquivo inteiro.